# Reading BerkeleyDB database rows in C#

Tags: c#, berkeley-db

I'm having some trouble reading rows from a berkeleyDB formatted file. I've used the db_dump utility to show what's in the file and there are lots of entries, but when I try via code I only get one row back from the cursor (a single key and 4 bytes of data)

```
DatabaseEntry foundKey = new DatabaseEntry();
DatabaseEntry foundData = new DatabaseEntry();
LockingInfo lockInfo = new LockingInfo();

BTreeCursor cursor = db.DB.Cursor();

while (cursor.MoveNext(foundKey, foundData, lockInfo))
{
    var kvp = cursor.CurrentMultiple;
    var keyString = Encoding.Default.GetString(foundKey.Data);
    var dataString = Encoding.Default.GetString(foundData.Data);
    Console.WriteLine($"{keyString}: {dataString}"); // output: main: 0002
    if(cursor.Count() > 1)
    {
        // count is always 1
        Console.WriteLine($"There are duplicate records.");
    }
}
cursor.Close();
db.DB.Close();
db.Environment.Close();
```

db_dump output:

```
VERSION=3
format=bytevalue
database=main
type=btree
db_pagesize=8192
HEADER=END
 0573262135f0b02634966b36b10c53c58fc6c3a2b8fff9e125be6ac3246..... (hundreds of lines)
DATA=END
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems I must pass the database name in order to read the data in the cursor.

When opening the database, I was originally using the following which only returned the database header when using the cursor:

```
db = BTreeDatabase.Open(filename, dbConfig, txn);
```

when I should have been using:

```
db = BTreeDatabase.Open(filename, "main", dbConfig, txn);
```